# Any interface for using KQL to ElasticSearch?

Tags: kql

We are using ElasticSearch for storing data, but the GUI/KQL/DSL languages are a real pain and is no where close to Kusto nor Splunk's SPL.
Any idea or any project to integrate Kusto language (KQL) to Elasticsearch? So that we can use KQL to extract data from ElasticSearch? Any tips/ideas on such would be great.

Answer (score 1):

To the best of my knowledge, Elasticsearch does not provide KQL support for its data. Building something like this is possible using the [Kusto Query Language parser](https://github.com/microsoft/Kusto-Query-Language) on github.

The main challenge of implementing a language created for one platform on another platform is that it is very likely that many operators and functions are not available on the other platform.

Comment: thanks @avnera. I was thinking to start a project to do bit by bit of the parser, but was checking if such a project was already available

Comment: Good luck! Feel free to ping me directly if you need any help with the KQL parser (my name at microsoft.com)